In pandas, how can I get a version of nth() to act as an aggregator?
In Pandas v1.x.x,
df.groupby("col").nth(0)

returned a dataframe that had "col" as the index col.
Now in pandas v2.x.x it doesn't, and my understanding of why is that nth is now seen as a "filter" and not an "aggregator".
I saw some threads that suggested I instead do
 df.groupby("col").nth(0).reset_index().set_index("col")

If I wanted a result with "col" as the index. This strikes me as crazy wordy, and duplicates code since I have to say "col" twice.
Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?  Bonus points if it is backwards compatible.

df.set_index('col').groupby(level=0).nth(0)

been a while @Ch3steR ... hope u are well and good

@sammywemmy I'm doing good. Hope you are doing great as well. yeah its been long time. Havent been active as much as I'd like to be but I know you got me covered with all the amazing answers. Good to see OGs still active in the community.

As suggested in comments, the most straightforward would be to set the column as index:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'val': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df.set_index('col').groupby(level=0).nth(0)

     val
col     
1    NaN
2    3.0

groupby.nth indeed does not behave like an aggregation function but rather like a filter. It can collect several values (making sense to keep the original index):
df.groupby('col').nth([0, 1])

   col  val
0    1  NaN
1    1  2.0
2    2  3.0
4    2  5.0

Setting col as index results in duplicated indices:
df.set_index('col').groupby(level=0).nth([0,1])

     val
col     
1    NaN
1    2.0
2    3.0
2    5.0

This is clearly discussed in the bug report #55334.
Note that for the specific case of nth(0), you could use:
df.groupby('col').first(skipna=False)

Or:
n = 0
df.groupby('col').agg(lambda x: x.iloc[n])

although this second option would fail if a group doesn't have a nth row.

The df.groupby('col').first(skipna=False) is what I was looking for (and df.groupby('col').last(skipna=False) for the last row).
